# syntax error while assigning list

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to solve a first order differential equation using Euler's method,  and then compare it with the actual solution by plotting them together using a range of 0 to 4 and 0.5 intervals. Below is the code.

It shows a syntax error at line 19(`array = []`). Can someone please explain why is it so?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def derivative(x):
    return (-2 * (x ** 3) + 12 * (x **2) - 20 * x + 8.5)

def value_new(value, derivative):
    return value + derivative * 0.5

def real_value(x):
    return (-0.5 * (x ** 4) + 4 * (x ** 3) - 10 * (x ** 2) + 8.5 * x + 1)

x = [0.5 * i for i in range(9)]
value = [1]

for i in x:
    y.append(value_new(y[-1], derivative(i))


actual = [] # this line shows invalid syntax

for i in x:
    actual.append(real_value(i))

plt.plot(x, value, x, actual, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis.

Comment: should be `y.append(value_new(y[-1], derivative(i)))`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the below line of code.

```
y.append(value_new(y[-1], derivative(i))
```

Add it and you should be good to go.

```
y.append(value_new(y[-1], derivative(i)))
```